# fatal error: cant open myprogram.exe

Tags: fatal-error

i dont know how to solve this problem considering it doesnt really pop up in the debugger as a problem with the code itself.
in the debugger it just says

"LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MyProgram.exe'"

when an option that says

"Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in MyProgram.exe.

Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate the program."
and i click break and go to some dissasembly menu with a list of numbers i dont know it has an arrow pointing to a line that says

"61D01661  and         dword ptr ds:[61D2D7A0h],0 "

if anyone has any info that can fix this problem it would be very helpful.

here is my code  (a program used to sort and count things about words in a text file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string word;

    ifstream testfile;
    vector <string> wordlist;
    bool isthere = false;
    vector <int> wordcountlist;
    int totalwords = 0;
    testfile.open("C:\\Users\\nothitler\\Desktop\\test.txt");
    //testfile.open("C:\\Users\\nothitler\\Desktop\\computer science\\computer science freshman semester 2\\1984.txt");
    while(testfile.good())
    {

        testfile >> word;
        for(int i=0; i <= wordlist.size(); i++) //goes through the word list checking if the words are equal
        {
            if(word == wordlist[i])
            {
                wordcountlist[i]++;
                isthere = true;
            }

        }
        if(isthere == false)
        {
            wordlist.push_back(word);
        }
        isthere = false;






        totalwords++;
        //cout << word << endl;

    }
    cout << totalwords << endl;
    for(int i=0; i <= wordlist.size(); i++) //displaying all the words in the list vector
    {
        cout<< wordlist[i];
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried launching your program using the debugger built into Visual Studio?  That should point you to the line of code causing the exception.

Comment: i have narrows the problem down to only being when there when i try to push_back.wordlist(word). am i doing something wrong with pushing back a string into a vector?.